# Does Private static variables gets shared with multiple sessions/user in web application?

Tags: c#

I am having MVC web application in which i have written some code to get forms cookie..Some times when i log out automatically some other users name were gets displays in text-box for which i have never logged in.I believe its due to private static variable but not sure.I have below code that i have implemented can anyone help me for this.Thanks

////This is code i am using to set from cookie

```
 private static string _formsCookieName;
        private static string FormsCookieName
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_formsCookieName))
                {
                    _formsCookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
                }
                return _formsCookieName;
            }
        }
        private static string _formsCookiePath;
        private static string FormsCookiePath
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_formsCookiePath))
                {
                    _formsCookiePath = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
                }
                return _formsCookiePath;
            }
        }


    public static UserSession LogoutAuthentication(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        UserSession session = null;
        string cookieName = FormsCookieName;
        try
        {
            HttpCookie httpCookie = context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
            httpCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now;
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        return session;
    }
```

Comment: When a variable is declared as static, then a single copy of the variable is created and shared among all objects at the class level

Comment: Quintium  thanks for your reply,here i have declared private static property and i dont know exactly that is it due to my above static code the formcookie is gets shared because the issue which i have mention is random not reproducible always but its criticle for me.

Comment: Try redirecting the user to home page/index after  FormsAuthentication.SignOut() call.

Comment: @Nair,Brother thats not the solution

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a static variable are shared amongst all threads.

Don't use static properties for values that should live only in the lifespam of your request. You can't even use `[ThreadStatic]` in asp.net because you don't control the thread pool, and the same thread can be reused to handle different requests .

And even when you DO want a static value that is mutated by different threads, you need to have locks in place to avoid race conditions.

Your `FormCookieName` class is request dependent, therefore it should only exist during the life spam of it. The poor man way of doing it would be to instantiate it in `Application_BeginRequest` and disposing it on `Application_EndRequest` of `Global.aspx.cs`, assuming `.NET Framework 4.5`.

The correct way of doing it, though, is using a DI container. They not only inject dependency, but manages the objects lifecycles. All major DI Containers have an HttpContext lifecycle manager of sorts, and .NET Core comes with a DI Container built in. In it, your code would become:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IFormsCookieName, FormsCookieName>();
}
```

And your controller:

```
public class FooController : ControllerBase
{
    public FooController(IFormsCookieName formsCookieName)
    {
        // receives a FormsCookieName instance that can safely use it's non-static properties
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Full configuration of Unity would be too long and off-topic for stack overflow. But the basic idea is that the Dependency Injector Container will create an instance of a non-static `FormsCookieName` in the scope of your `HttpContext` and then dispose that and the end of the request. This ensures that every `HttpContext` gets it's own copy of `FormsCookieName`and no data will mess up.

I recommend [unity](https://github.com/unitycontainer/container) as DI Container. It's maintained by Microsoft, and it's performance has seen a lot of improvements in latest versions.

[Configuring a DI Container isn't hard](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/777401/Configure-Unity-for-ASP-NET-MVC-Up-and-Running), and provides lots of benefits.

Comment: Hi Ortiga,Thanks for your feedback but can you explain me in detail like how we should use your example instead of my code because its random that i am getting other user values...

Comment: @SahadShaikh which framework version are you using? dotnet core or `framework 4.5-`? Do you have any dependency injection container set up in your project?

Comment: 4.5 framwork besically its a MVC project...No dependency Injection is implemented..

Comment: @SahadShaikh See the edit part of my answer. I've included a link for unity configuration in an MVC project. If you face any problems configuring it, feel free to ask.